# Redis subscriber is not notified by EXPIRE key 0

Tags: events, redis

I've got a Redis client subscribed to `__keyevent@0__:expired` notifications. It works perfectly, either when the key expires by itself (ttl reached) or when I expire them manually with a number of seconds greater than 0, like so:

```
EXPIRE myKey 1
```

The subscriber sees the `expired` event and can therefore take some actions.

However, if I want to manually **delete** the key **and** have the subscriber notified, I use `EXPIRE` with 0 as the number of seconds:

```
EXPIRE myKey 0
```

The key gets deleted, but the subscriber doesn't receive anything.

I can't see anything related to this in the doc. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reviewing the source code (expire.c, ~252), setting an expiry value of <=0 (or using EXPIREAT with a time in the past) results in a deletion of the key rather than an expiry (and accordingly a DEL notification rather than an EXPIRED event).

This behavior is indeed undocumented and it would be good if you could submit a PR that fixes that to the documentation repo (https://github.com/antirez/redis-doc).